# Numpy: concatenate different dtypes whilst preserving each dtype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 3 arrays which I want to concatenate along axis 1. Their dtypes are np.float32, U32 and np.float32.
When I concatenate like this:

```
np.concatenate((A,B,C), axis=1)
```

the dtype of the result is 'U32'. I want preserve the float32 dtypes of columns A and C. How do I do this?

Comment: normal numpy array accept one dtype per array , U32 >np.float32

Comment: You can use structured arrays, but probably better is to use Pandas.

Comment: You have 2 options.  An object dtype array or a structured array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with structured arrays (or record arrays).
If `A`, `B` and `C` are defined as

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros(30, dtype=np.float32)
B = np.zeros(30, dtype=np.int32)
C = np.zeros(30, dtype=np.float32)
```

You can create a record array with

```py
res = np.rec.fromarrays([A,B,C], names='a,b,c')
```

A,B, and C must have the same shape, but they can have any datatype you choose.  The sub-arrays (or fields) can be accessed with `res.a` or `res['a']`.  Most operations (`mean`, `max`, etc.) can't operate on the whole array.  You'll need to select an individual field, but indexing and related operations will work on the whole array.
Structured arrays are a very useful object once you get used to working with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a numpy array with dtype=object. It allows you to mix types. Here is an example.

```
integer = [1, 5]
floats =[3., 4.]
mixed  = np.array( [integer, floats], dtype=object)
mixed 
out[4]:
array([[1, 5],
[3.0, 4.0]], dtype=object)
```